My Roblox Code for a leaderstat won't reset and should include the current stage and the maximum stage
(I would've asked this on the Dev Forum, but I haven't been cleared)
So I'm making a basic obby in order to learn the different aspects of the game.  I found an script to record the player leaderstats but noticed that, after I published it, it would save the stage and constantly had me load up at my most recent stage.  I tried searching online and looking through the code but it doesn't make sense to me.
Below is the code:
local dataStoreService = game:GetService("DataStoreService")
local stageStore = dataStoreService:GetDataStore("PlayerStageDataStore")
function plrToStage(plr)
    repeat wait() until plr.Character.HumanoidRootPart
    local stagePart = game.Workspace.Checkpoints:FindFirstChild(tostring(plr.leaderstats.Stage.Value))
    plr.Character.HumanoidRootPart.CFrame = stagePart.CFrame + Vector3.new(0,2.5,0)
end
game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(player)
    local leaderstats = Instance.new("Folder")
    leaderstats.Name = "leaderstats"
    leaderstats.Parent = player
    local stage = Instance.new("IntValue")
    stage.Name = "Stage"
    stage.Parent = leaderstats
    local success, errorMsg = pcall(function()
        stage.Value = stageStore:GetAsync(player.UserId)
    end)
    if success then
        print("Successfully got "..player.Name.."'s stage data.")
    else
        warn(errorMsg)
    end

    if player.Character then
        plrToStage(player)
    end
    player.CharacterAdded:Connect(function()
        plrToStage(player)
    end)
end)
game.Players.PlayerRemoving:Connect(function(player)
    local success, errorMsg = pcall(function()
        stageStore:SetAsync(player.UserId,player.leaderstats.Stage.Value)
    end)
    if success then
        print("Successfully got "..player.Name.."'s stage data.")
    else
        warn(errorMsg)
    end 
end)
for _, cheackpoint in pairs(game.Workspace.Checkpoints:GetChildren()) do
    cheackpoint.Touched:Connect(function(hit)
        if hit.Parent:FindFirstChild("Humanoid") then
            local player = game.Players:GetPlayerFromCharacter(hit.Parent)

        local cheackpointNumber = tonumber(cheackpoint.Name)

            if player.leaderstats.Stage.Value < cheackpointNumber then
                player.leaderstats.Stage.Value = cheackpointNumber
            end
        end
    end)
end

Using the code, the player continues to load up at the highest reached stage.  To be clear, this isn't referring to them dying and respawning at the last checkpoint, but that when I leave the game and return, I will always jump to my last stage (while also saying that I'm at level 1 until it updates at the next highest checkpoint).
I was hoping to alter the code so that:
(a) The leaderstats show the details of the current stage of the player as well as the maximum stage that the player has reached.
(b) Save the max stage so that it is up to date whenever they log it.
(c) Reset their current stage to 1 so that they start at the beginning of the level.
